# How to load configurations from toml file, for a particular field, in an un-nested way in Rust?

Tags: rust, config, toml

I want to load configuration values from the toml file.

I defined the struct in the generic settings file (that has the functions like `load`). I, then, defined a struct Wrapper and implemented it. And eveerything worked fine.

However, my ultimate aim is to remove the unneeded and extra layer of abstraction from the load of settings.

When I try to define the struct and ControlPlaneSynchronizerSettings and load it directly, instead of building the Wrapper, I get the error that `offset_column_name` not found.

Below is the non-working code, with the commented out part highlighting the working code:

```
use some_module::settings::LoadableSettings;
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_with::serde_as;
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct ControlPlaneSynchronizerSettings {
    pub offset_column_name: String,
    pub environment_column_name: String,
 
}

// #[serde_as]
// #[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, Clone)]
// pub struct Wrapper {
//     pub controlplanesynchronizersettings: ControlPlaneSynchronizerSettings,
// }

// impl Wrapper {
//     pub fn new_or_panic() -> Self {
//         match Self::load() {
//             Ok(s) => s,
//             Err(e) => panic!("Error loading config: {:?}", e),
//         }
//     }
// }

impl ControlPlaneSynchronizerSettings {
    pub fn new_or_panic() -> Self {
        match Self::load() {
            Ok(s) => s,
            Err(e) => panic!("Error loading config: {e}"),
        }
    }
}
```

Command I run:
`cargo run`

Error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error loading config: missing field `offset_column_name`', control-plane-synchronizer/src/settings.rs:52:23
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

TOML file:

```
[controlplanesynchronizersettings]
offset_column_name = "offset"
environment_column_name = "environment"
<continued definition>
```

Comment: Why not just remove the line `[controlplanesynchronizersettings]` from your toml?

Comment: That is not possible due to organization of configs - its a large config file and organization is necessary.

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple other `[section]`s?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple other sections.

Comment: Why are you trying to load one section on its own instead of the whole file at once?

Comment: The layer is not unneeded, since it's part of the file. The "wrapper" represents the entire file. If you don't care to have a structure for the file, you can just deserialize to an untyped `toml::Table`, `get` (or index) the section you care about from the top-level table, then deserialize from the `toml::Value` to your typed structure.

Comment: >Why are you trying to load one section on its own instead of the whole file at once? – 

I am not trying to load only one section. The other sections are loaded in different parts of the monorepo. I am only concerned with this section though.